# Embedded Google form not working on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, google-forms

Embedded Google form not working on Wordpress
I am trying to embed a Google Form on a Wordpress site (made with Elementor). I know the basic steps, but when I hit publish, the form just says "loading." A hard refresh and clearing the cache doesn't help. here is the page: https://unlockmysim.com/service-unavailable/
Any suggestions?

Hard refresh, clearing cache, editing form code

Loading…

Comment: Hi, maybe it would be helpful to provide the WordPress version and and the code you are using for this.

Comment: In elementor builder there was 2 different html elements. I had originally used the element labeled " custom html"  and i switched to the one labeled "html" and now the form loads correctly. Thanks for the responses.

Answer (score 1):

Once you click the embed form option, you will see the embed code with some customization options. Enter the desired values in the fields, and hit copy.

After that head over to your WordPress site’s admin area and edit the post or page where you want to display the form.

On the post edit screen, you will need to switch to the **text editor** and then paste your form code.

If not working Check again code in the **text editor**
May be It has some missing parts in the embed code.

[image]